# C# list of custom class .Contains()

Tags: c#

i have a list of custom class and before adding to the list i want to check if the list has the same instance (not one attribute - all of them)

```
public class Function
{
    public string Name;
    public string RT;
    public int ParamCount;
    public List<string> ParamDT;
    public Function()
    {
        ParamDT = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

i tried overriding Equals() and GetHashCode()
but it didn't work
Equals()

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = obj as Function;

        if (item == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.Name == item.Name && this.RT == item.RT &&
            this.ParamCount == item.ParamCount && this.ParamDT.Equals(item.ParamDT);
    }
```

GetHashCode()

```
public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the Equals/hashcode method please. Would a set not be a better data structure if you want only one instance of each type

Comment: `GetHashCode` must build a hash code from all the properties or fields checked in `Equals` to be consistent with `Equals`. This is important if you are adding objects to a `HashSet<Function>` or if you use them as a key in a `Dictionary<K, V>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParamDT is also a list, you have to check its items also individually to compare properly.

```
this.ParamDT.Equals(item.ParamDT);
```

Having said that, list is not the structure you should be using if you want single instances of your object. There is a lot of overhead trying to search for equality in list as you will be searching the entire list. Try to use a set/dictionary based structure.

Your implementation of `GetHasCode` function is also not proper. It is based only on `Name` property while in equality you are using all the properties, this will lead to undesirable characteristics. Please read the [MSDN documentatio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Object_GetHashCode)n for a better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is below:

```
    protected bool Equals(Function other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Name, other.Name) && string.Equals(RT, other.RT) && ParamCount == other.ParamCount && Equals(ParamDT, other.ParamDT);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Function) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (RT != null ? RT.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ ParamCount;
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (ParamDT != null ? ParamDT.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
```

you can then use a HashSet which is a collection that contains no duplicate elements. This will ensure there is no code written for checking uniqueness in List. Link is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2